# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Connections!
I am facing an error as :
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'query' referenced before assignment for the same piece of code I have attached below. Can anyone help me out for solving the problem ?

```
def takecommand() :
    command = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening....')
        command.pause_threshold = 1.2
        audio = command.listen(source)

        try:
            print('Recognizing...')
            query = command.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print('You Said : ',query)

        except Exception as e :
            assistant.say('I cannot recognize, Please say again')

        return query.lower()
```

Comment: What happens if you encounter an `Exception`? What value will `query` have in your opinion and why?

Comment: `command.recognize_google` raised an exception, so nothing was assigned to `query`. You cannot `return query.lower()` in case of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the code inside the try / except block raises an exception, the variable query won't be created. At the end of your code, you try to return query.lower(), and since it hasn't been defined, it raises that error. You can solve this problem in two different ways.

**1:**
Creating the variable before the try / except block

```
def takecommand():
command = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Listening....')
    command.pause_threshold = 1.2
    audio = command.listen(source)
    
query = "Not recognized"

try:
    print('Recognizing...')
    query = command.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
    print('You Said : ',query)

except Exception as e :
    assistant.say('I cannot recognize, Please say again')

return query.lower()
```

**2:**
Returning the query.lower inside the try block. *Note: It will return None if it raises an exception. You should handle it.

```
def takecommand():
command = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Listening....')
    command.pause_threshold = 1.2
    audio = command.listen(source)

try:
    print('Recognizing...')
    query = command.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
    print('You Said : ',query)
    return query.lower()

except Exception as e :
    assistant.say('I cannot recognize, Please say again')
```